# Checking what character has been "backspaced"

Tags: c#, winforms

How would I determine the character which been backspaced and then play out the following conditions:

- If the character backspaced is after "." then `count=0`
- If the character backspaced is "." then `dotControl=false` and `count=0`

Code below:

```
    private void RemoveLast(TextBox tb)
    {
        if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1, 1);
        }
    }

    private void btnback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (remainTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(remainTxt);
        }
        else if (totalTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(totalTxt);
        }
        else if (paidTxt.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(245, 244, 162))
        {
            RemoveLast(paidTxt);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
{
   if(char.IsDigit(tb.Text[tb.Text.Length - 1]) count = 0;
   else 
   { 
       dotControl = false;
       count = 0;
   }
    tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1, 1);
}
```

By the way second `count = 0` (in else statement) is redundant I guess,user can enter one digit after dot,so if he click back and delete one digit count will be zero.

Comment: You answered his last question.  lol is this a conspiracy? ;)  Good answer. +1